# Postgres: Why won't EF Core 3 scaffold from the CLI

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

When I try to

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold name=myconnection Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL -o Models -v^
```

It fails with the following

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.RelationalAnnotations' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Scaffolding.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseModelFactory.GetExtensions(NpgsqlConnection connection, DatabaseModel databaseModel)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Scaffolding.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseModelFactory.Create(DbConnection dbConnection, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions options)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Scaffolding.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions options)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineerScaffolder.ScaffoldModel(String connectionString, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions databaseOptions, ModelReverseEngineerOptions modelOptions, ModelCodeGenerationOptions codeOptions)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputDbContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.RelationalAnnotations' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
```

I've tried a bunch of stuff. I need to use the v3 stuff because the genius who designed the database decided not to add primary keys to the umpteen tables.

To reproduce this:
-create a db in postgres with no primary keys
-install .netcore sdk 3x
- create a new project (i've tried console and mvc to no avail) and add your connection string to appsettings.json

-install the following nuget packages

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0-preview6.19307.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.0.0-preview6.19304.10" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="3.0.0-preview6.19304.10" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0-preview6.19304.10" />
<PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="3.0.0-preview5" />
```

-

AFAIK, this process should provide models for all the tables. What am I missing?

Comment: Without keys, you'll only be able to query the entities.  Is that what you want?

Comment: There are id fields, they are just inconsistently named and they are not set as PK in postgres. Why would i only be able to query?

Comment: Entities without keys cannot be modified, and the EF Core 3 feature you are referring to is to scaffold these read-only Query Types.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types  You should stick to EF Core 2, and just scaffold the tables manually, or start with a copy of the database that has the primary keys defined, if you want EF to to the scaffolding.